# How to remove table row based on contents of one of the cells in the row (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I'm trying to delete one row in a dynamically generated table; the problems is that none of these rows have any class or ids generated and I can't get at the code. It generates code like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="label">Who referred you?</td>
    <td class="data">somebody</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">terms</td>
    <td class="data">these are the terms</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any way to get at the row that has "terms" (in this case the 2nd row) and delete that whole row? Something with the `text()` and `filter()` that I don't understand?  I know I can delete the second row easily, but sometimes it will be the second and sometime not.

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery:

```
$(".profile-fields tr:contains('terms')").remove();​​​​
```

[see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/HapjP/3/)

without jQuery (if speed is a concern):

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = rows.length; i--;) {
  if(rows[i].innerHTML.indexOf("terms") !== -1) {
    rows[i].parentNode.removeChild( rows[i] );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, i figured it out:

> $j(".profile-fields
>   td:contains('terms')").parent().remove();